# My wifi works when I boot into windows, but not Linux mint

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, iwlwifi

I'm using Linux Mint right now, connected to the router with Ethernet. When I put in the password for the wifi, it goes into a loop where it keeps asking me for me system password, saying "Authentication required by Wi-Fi network", while never connecting.

Results of iwconfig:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp0s31f6  no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    no wireless extensions.

enx325714533016  no wireless extensions.
```

Results of lsmod | grep iwlwifi:

```
iwlwifi               507904  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              942080  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
compat                 16384  4 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211,cfg80211
```

(iwlwifi is red if that means anything)

Edit: result of lscpci -nn

paste-bin.xyz/72628

Comment: What is your wifi-card? Check `lspci -nn`.

Comment: @FelixJN https://paste-bin.xyz/72628

Comment: Well ... Kindly add the respective line to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works now.I needed to enable Wifi in the NetworkManager